# Notebook's battery consumption based on OS

Tags: windows-7, linux, laptop, battery, power-management

I use notebook to do typing, programming, browsing interne, downloading updates and so on. I use the same tasks on both Linux x64 and Windows 7 x64. My internet usage (browsing, downloading OS updates, downloading Linux packages) is higher and longer on ***Linux***. But I noticed (I examined it, indeed) that while on ***Windows***, my battery power lasts - considerably - less than Linux. Is there any technical reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

This differs from build to build in my experience. Sometimes Linux uses substantially more. All else being equal (same resolution etc,.) I think it is mostly graphics related, ie,. due to the vid adaptor and drivers. But other drivers are more than likely involved as well.

So if you want to tweak best battery life that is where to look, look for documentation on the drivers and chipset. Software used can also be an issue if your Windows installation is high CPU usage this will affect battery life as well. So for instance a basic Windows installation will last longer on battery than one loaded with all sorts of goodies that run all the time.

In answer to your question, drivers for the hardware are the most likely culprit. Software the next.

If you're using Linux without a GUI, then that also makes a big difference to power consumption.